# How to export/save an animated bubble chart made with plotly?

Tags: python, animation, charts, plotly

How to export/save an animated bubble chart made with plotly? (For instance, the one was made following the link below) I would like to have it in a gift or some format with better resolution. Thank you in advance.

https://www.kaggle.com/aashita/guide-to-animated-bubble-charts-using-plotly

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue? Please accept and upvote, if it did so. :) Cheers

Answer (score 8):

There is no possibility to do this in plotly. Please use `gifmaker` and save every step in the animation as a single picture to later combine them to a gif. [Follow this source](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/664). Further explanation on how to create animations is provided by plotly [here](https://plot.ly/python/animations/).

The basic way to go would be to integrate this logic into the animation process of your plotly code:

```
 import ImageSequence
 import Image
 import gifmaker
 sequence = []

 im = Image.open(....)

 # im is your original image
 frames = [frame.copy() for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im)]

 # write GIF animation
 fp = open("out.gif", "wb")
 gifmaker.makedelta(fp, frames)
 fp.close()
```

If you could provide your actual code, it would be possible to provide a more detailled answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use the [gif](https://pypi.org/project/gif/) library, which works with matplolib, altair and plotly, and is really straight forward. In this case you would not use a plotly animation. Instead, you define a function that returns a plotly fig and construct a list of figs to pass to gif as an argument.

Your code would look something like this:

```
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import gif

# Pandas DataFrame with random data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    't': list(range(10)) * 10,
    'x': [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)],
    'y': [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)]
})

# Gif function definition
@gif.frame
def plot(i):
    d = df[df['t'] == i]
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=d["x"],
        y=d["y"],
        mode="markers"
    ))
    fig.update_layout(width=500, height=300)
    return fig

# Construct list of frames
frames = []
for i in range(10):
    frame = plot(i)
    frames.append(frame)

# Save gif from frames with a specific duration for each frame in ms
gif.save(frames, 'example.gif', duration=100)
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on answers already provided.   This generates an animated GIF from an **plotly** figure that has frames (is animated)

- start by generating some test data
- generate an animated figure using **plotly express**
- create an image for each frame in **plotly** figure
- finally generate animated GIF from list of images

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import PIL

r = np.random.RandomState(42)

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "step": np.repeat(np.arange(0, 8), 10),
        "x": np.tile(np.linspace(0, 9, 10), 8),
        "y": r.uniform(0, 5, 80),
    }
)

# smaple plotly animated figure
fig = px.bar(df, x="x", y="y", animation_frame="step")

# generate images for each step in animation
frames = []
for s, fr in enumerate(fig.frames):
    # set main traces to appropriate traces within plotly frame
    fig.update(data=fr.data)
    # move slider to correct place
    fig.layout.sliders[0].update(active=s)
    # generate image of current state
    frames.append(PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(fig.to_image(format="png"))))
    
# create animated GIF
frames[0].save(
        "test.gif",
        save_all=True,
        append_images=frames[1:],
        optimize=True,
        duration=500,
        loop=0,
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent work! Haven't seen this before. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would post the solution I found to this problem that I think might be a little easier depending on your circumstances. This Solution worked for me and only uses the Pillow external library.

```py
import PIL.Image
import io
import plotly.express as px

# Generate your animated plot.
plot = px.bar(data_frame=your_data, x=your_x, y=your_y, animation_frame=your_af)

# Save each plot frame to a list that is used to generate the .gif file. 
frames = []
for slider_pos, frame in enumerate(plot.frames):
    plot.update(data=frame.data)
    plot.layout.sliders[0].update(active=slider_pos)
    frames.append(PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(plot.to_image(format="png"))))
    
# Create the gif file.
frames[0].save("out_dir",
               save_all=True,
               append_images=frames[1:],
               optimize=True,
               duration=1000,
               loop=0)
```

The loop state of the gif can be controlled with the loop argument - 0 implies it will repeat infinitely. The duration argument implies the number of milliseconds between frames.