# Is there a way to insert interactive animations from python plotly to a powerpoint?

Tags: python, powerpoint

I want to insert the plotly interactive animation into a powerpoint. I read online that you can generate a gif, however I want to be able to use the animation bar that you get from plotly on the powerpoint slide. Is there any way to do that? Sorry if this is a stupid question, this is my first time doing something like that.

Comment: Please visit https://towardsdatascience.com/embed-interactive-plots-in-your-slides-with-plotly-fde92a5865a

Comment: Also this link https://plotly.com/python/presentations-tool/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460434/how-to-export-save-an-animated-bubble-chart-made-with-plotly describes how to create animated GIFs. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-animated-gif-to-a-slide-3a04f755-25a9-42c4-8cc1-1da4148aef01 describes how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting an extension that allows embedding the plotly webpage you have into powerpoint. How well this works will depend on the specifics of the extension you choose to use.

There is some discussion about embedding iframes into powerpoint here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-embed-iframe-code-into-my-powerpoint/5b7b5bc9-a68b-46d9-88ad-207387d621b7