# Plotly Mapbox Animation, is there a way to keep data frame by frame?

Tags: python, animation, plotly, mapbox

I'm learning python and am trying to make an animated map of uk car accidents. I am wondering if there is a way to hold data from shown frames, and keep it there, while the newer frames add on.

As of right now the animation plays week by week data over a year.

I have looked for more resources on this but could not find anything. If anyone has any idea how I could make this work it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

````
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(collision_df,
                        lat="latitude" ,
                        lon="longitude",
                        color="accident_severity",
                        color_discrete_map = {
                            'Non-Fatal':'#272b9b',
                            'Fatal':'#b22f20'
                        },
                        size = "number_of_casualties",
                        size_max = 10,
                        opacity=0.5,
                        hover_name='accident_severity',
                        hover_data=hover_data_dict,
                        animation_frame="week_date_range",
                        mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                        category_orders={
                            "week_date_range": list(np.sort(collision_df['week_date_range'].unique()))
                        },
                        zoom=4.6,
                       center={})```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export/save an animated bubble chart made with plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460434/how-to-export-save-an-animated-bubble-chart-made-with-plotly)

Comment: This may also help: [How to export animation and save it in a video format like mp4,mpeg or… (community.plotly.com)](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-export-animation-and-save-it-in-a-video-format-like-mp4-mpeg-or/64621)